# Try request on website with around 5000 length in url

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

On this website [https://www.bezrealitky.cz](https://www.bezrealitky.cz/) i try request for information but the url is around 5000 length long and i get nothing in output.

I try this code:

```
import gspread
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cast_2 = "7460372%2C50.0646836%5D%2C%5B14.7483696%2C50.0612238%5D%2C%5B14.7483383%2C50.0583969%5D%2C%5B14.7546239%2C50.0529376%5D%2C%5B14.7515918%2C50.04738%5D%2C%5B14.7528839%2C50.0403354%5D%2C%5B14.7493543%2C50.0391631%5D%2C%5B14.7512053%2C50.0370347%5D%2C%5B14.7504488%2C50.0345038%5D%2C%5B14.7529152%2C50.0334157%5D%2C%5B14.7549521%2C50.0273482%5D%2C%5B14.7510315%2C50.0233121%5D%2C%5B14.7613824%2C50.0237208%5D%2C%5B14.7636167%2C50.0221496%5D%2C%5B14.7637296%2C50.0164491%5D%2C%5B14.7615743%2C50.012857%5D%2C%5B14.7706651%2C50.0100383%5D%2C%5B14.7881162%2C50.0135281%5D%2C%5B14.7975388%2C50.0122003%5D%2C%5B14.8027277%2C50.0136821%5D%2C%5B14.8061398%2C50.0114449%5D%2C%5B14.8061581%2C50.0065423%5D%2C%5B14.8078741%2C50.0060327%5D%2C%5B14.8079901%2C50.0075185%5D%2C%5B14.8115355%2C50.0091465%5D%2C%5B14.8167724%2C50.00864%5D%2C%5B14.8310856%2C50.0172897%5D%2C%5B14.8338134%2C50.0171025%5D%2C%5B14.8342407%2C50.0124198%5D%2C%5B14.8362383%2C50.011968%5D%2C%5B14.8368206%2C50.016655%5D%2C%5B14.8543707%2C50.0161536%5D%2C%5B14.8565756%2C50.0177261%5D%2C%5B14.8570572%2C50.0213736%5D%2C%5B14.8498872%2C50.0278437%5D%2C%5B14.8536689%2C50.0320382%5D%2C%5B14.8620365%2C50.0331695%5D%2C%5B14.8699823%2C50.029833%5D%2C%5B14.8686147%2C50.0169813%5D%2C%5B14.8666129%2C50.013744%5D%2C%5B14.8682312%2C50.0096072%5D%2C%5B14.883544%2C50.0078683%5D%2C%5B14.8816725%2C50.0059146%5D%2C%5B14.8807235%2C50.0006693%5D%2C%5B14.8870952%2C50.0005446%5D%2C%5B14.8867784%2C49.9967618%5D%2C%5B14.890288%2C49.9920084%5D%2C%5B14.9000404%2C49.9936546%5D%2C%5B14.9089142%2C49.989327%5D%2C%5B14.9090253%2C49.9904781%5D%2C%5B14.9180098%2C49.9911811%5D%2C%5B14.9212725%2C49.9857218%5D%2C%5B14.9192363%2C49.9845855%5D%2C%5B14.9203582%2C49.983578%5D%2C%5B14.9269916%2C49.9858337%5D%2C%5B14.928416%2C49.9890091%5D%2C%5B14.9306597%2C49.9900138%5D%2C%5B14.9311636%2C49.9882144%5D%2C%5B14.9367484%2C49.9906851%5D%2C%5B14.9419242%2C49.9895189%5D%2C%5B14.9359828%2C49.9863591%5D%2C%5B14.9382795%2C49.981983%5D%2C%5B14.931343%2C49.9780358%5D%2C%5B14.9303346%2C49.9724941%5D%2C%5B14.932246%2C49.9674614%5D%2C%5B14.9280618%2C49.9579488%5D%2C%5B14.9331609%2C49.9577085%5D%2C%5B14.9306572%2C49.9527402%5D%2C%5B14.9274264%2C49.9509742%5D%2C%5B14.9302193%2C49.9495788%5D%2C%5B14.9292025%2C49.9481072%5D%2C%5B14.9263141%2C49.9481936%5D%2C%5B14.9261212%2C49.9456787%5D%2C%5B14.9275244%2C49"
cast_3 = ".9455488%5D%2C%5B14.9257431%2C49.9451039%5D%2C%5B14.9243516%2C49.9420148%5D%2C%5B14.9336951%2C49.9390724%5D%2C%5B14.9285746%2C49.9375499%5D%2C%5B14.9232954%2C49.9391386%5D%2C%5B14.9185643%2C49.9523745%5D%2C%5B14.9095933%2C49.9529501%5D%2C%5B14.8981181%2C49.9476337%5D%2C%5B14.8907048%2C49.9392604%5D%2C%5B14.8915933%2C49.936355%5D%2C%5B14.8864724%2C49.9375382%5D%2C%5B14.8867596%2C49.9356867%5D%2C%5B14.8899145%2C49.9313207%5D%2C%5B14.8933734%2C49.9300241%5D%2C%5B14.8964743%2C49.923446%5D%2C%5B14.9025013%2C49.919721%5D%2C%5B14.9047702%2C49.9164821%5D%2C%5B14.9176309%2C49.9175431%5D%2C%5B14.9164319%2C49.9200692%5D%2C%5B14.9175303%2C49.9225778%5D%2C%5B14.9289145%2C49.917223%5D%2C%5B14.9330489%2C49.9168551%5D%2C%5B14.9372387%2C49.9075293%5D%2C%5B14.9352755%2C49.9066415%5D%2C%5B14.9411617%2C49.9029621%5D%2C%5B14.940379%2C49.8993594%5D%2C%5B14.935669%2C49.8952156%5D%2C%5B14.9384554%2C49.8917643%5D%2C%5B14.9472443%2C49.8880358%5D%2C%5B14.9528711%2C49.8883229%5D%2C%5B14.9545243%2C49.8889728%5D%2C%5B14.9555799%2C49.8961729%5D%2C%5B14.9607454%2C49.8965317%5D%2C%5B14.9606301%2C49.8945635%5D%2C%5B14.9635334%2C49.8942765%5D%2C%5B14.9624936%2C49.8932596%5D%2C%5B14.9674574%2C49.8925867%5D%2C%5B14.9724662%2C49.8948229%5D%2C%5B14.9714967%2C49.8966132%5D%2C%5B14.9725729%2C49.8995754%5D%2C%5B14.9759147%2C49.898875%5D%2C%5B14.9769214%2C49.9004331%5D%2C%5B14.9846763%2C49.9007413%5D%2C%5B14.9865037%2C49.9003017%5D%2C%5B14.986104%2C49.8976845%5D%2C%5B14.9911552%2C49.8945319%5D%2C%5B14.9874514%2C49.8896809%5D%2C%5B14.9946711%2C49.8895076%5D%2C%5B14.9915024%2C49.8850037%5D%2C%5B14.9947409%2C49.8846719%5D%2C%5B14.9958491%2C49.8802898%5D%2C%5B14.999003%2C49.8823417%5D%2C%5B15.0053515%2C49.8830424%5D%2C%5B15.0099309%2C49.8795241%5D%2C%5B15.0124418%2C49.8801023%5D%2C%5B15.011424%2C49.8899134%5D%2C%5B15.01354%2C49.8915423%5D%2C%5B15.0122471%2C49.8921134%5D%2C%5B15.0142633%2C49.8934424%5D%2C%5B15.0140542%2C49.8954869%5D%2C%5B15.0189515%2C49.8949809%5D%2C%5B15.0194431%2C49.8989414%5D%2C%5B15.0243348%2C49.9005027%5D%2C%5B15.020474%2C49.905695%5D%2C%5B15.0219726%2C49.9095088%5D%2C%5B15.0272693%2C49.9116921%5D%2C%5B15.0263371%2C49.9142298%5D%2C%5B15.022275%2C49.9153146%5D%2C%5B15.0219879%2C49.9204434%5D%2C%5B15.023551%2C49.9231595%5D%2C%5B15.029706%2C49.9239071%5D%2C%5B15.0292901%2C49.9265814%5D%2C%5B15.0353043%2C49.927282%5D%2C%5B15"
cast_4 = ".0400271%2C49.9230311%5D%2C%5B15.0390876%2C49.9223017%5D%2C%5B15.0426921%2C49.9214656%5D%2C%5B15.042195%2C49.919563%5D%2C%5B15.056001%2C49.9151051%5D%2C%5B15.0694879%2C49.9139673%5D%2C%5B15.0699502%2C49.9155857%5D%2C%5B15.0747277%2C49.9154931%5D%2C%5B15.0746215%2C49.9175953%5D%2C%5B15.0802883%2C49.9195617%5D%2C%5B15.078314%2C49.9228952%5D%2C%5B15.0796324%2C49.923096%5D%2C%5B15.0901438%2C49.9218556%5D%2C%5B15.0929845%2C49.9233777%5D%2C%5B15.103518%2C49.9187582%5D%2C%5B15.1029777%2C49.9314127%5D%2C%5B15.1144736%2C49.9345202%5D%2C%5B15.1102589%2C49.9420706%5D%2C%5B15.1158032%2C49.9422821%5D%2C%5B15.1165203%2C49.944272%5D%2C%5B15.1145739%2C49.945346%5D%2C%5B15.1171915%2C49.9488564%5D%2C%5B15.1276201%2C49.9512419%5D%2C%5B15.1274718%2C49.955674%5D%2C%5B15.1517372%2C49.9531124%5D%2C%5B15.1526448%2C49.9567041%5D%2C%5B15.1586225%2C49.9561615%5D%2C%5B15.1598926%2C49.962716%5D%2C%5B15.1662636%2C49.9630819%5D%2C%5B15.1715054%2C49.9584597%5D%2C%5B15.1774664%2C49.9591787%5D%2C%5B15.1810824%2C49.956233%5D%2C%5B15.1810663%2C49.9526501%5D%2C%5B15.1862035%2C49.9530225%5D%2C%5B15.1952391%2C49.9578357%5D%2C%5B15.2115243%2C49.9592322%5D%2C%5B15.2139904%2C49.9620232%5D%2C%5B15.2170339%2C49.9610558%5D%2C%5B15.2230008%2C49.9622295%5D%2C%5B15.2265423%2C49.9759596%5D%2C%5B15.2333309%2C49.975372%5D%2C%5B15.2348486%2C49.97927%5D%2C%5B15.2407609%2C49.978409%5D%2C%5B15.2397699%2C49.9807084%5D%2C%5B15.2425184%2C49.9817658%5D%2C%5B15.2446314%2C49.9818782%5D%2C%5B15.2442988%2C49.9775396%5D%2C%5B15.2472652%2C49.9768984%5D%2C%5B15.2480568%2C49.9718284%5D%2C%5B15.2507013%2C49.9708684%5D%2C%5B15.2517455%2C49.9680948%5D%2C%5B15.2577153%2C49.9664238%5D%2C%5B15.2596658%2C49.9691599%5D%2C%5B15.2620682%2C49.9693487%5D%2C%5B15.2582713%2C49.9773754%5D%2C%5B15.2607681%2C49.9811908%5D%2C%5B15.2624639%2C49.9805064%5D%2C%5B15.2673975%2C49.988205%5D%2C%5B15.2760691%2C49.9856889%5D%2C%5B15.2782403%2C49.9882659%5D%2C%5B15.2673699%2C49.9908658%5D%2C%5B15.268852%2C49.9939161%5D%2C%5B15.2710964%2C49.9936841%5D%2C%5B15.2693211%2C49.994915%5D%2C%5B15.2713724%2C49.9974748%5D%2C%5B15.2748592%2C49.9976762%5D%2C%5B15.2784299%2C49.9949788%5D%2C%5B15.2806409%2C50.0003848%5D%2C%5B15.2903084%2C50.0004699%5D%2C%5B15.2904481%2C50.0038247%5D%2C%5B15.2942844%2C50.0041151%5D%2C%5B15.2950376%2C50.003145%5D%2C%5B15.2912638%2C50.0001124%5D%2C%5B15.297798%2C49.9966362%5D%2C%5B15"
cast_5 = ".3030433%2C49.9978618%5D%2C%5B15.3065558%2C50.0010961%5D%2C%5B15.3176203%2C49.9958783%5D%2C%5B15.3209257%2C49.9957084%5D%2C%5B15.3218971%2C49.9940926%5D%2C%5B15.3251451%2C49.9942954%5D%2C%5B15.310632%2C50.000222%5D%2C%5B15.3115761%2C50.0052775%5D%2C%5B15.3181268%2C50.0036175%5D%2C%5B15.3095883%2C50.0068186%5D%2C%5B15.3288149%2C50.0102639%5D%2C%5B15.3278347%2C50.0129677%5D%2C%5B15.3228156%2C50.014841%5D%2C%5B15.3226442%2C50.0161805%5D%2C%5B15.3168893%2C50.0158068%5D%2C%5B15.3168707%2C50.0183363%5D%2C%5B15.3099008%2C50.0173573%5D%2C%5B15.3100671%2C50.0223491%5D%2C%5B15.3146543%2C50.0224925%5D%2C%5B15.3181523%2C50.0207887%5D%2C%5B15.3233162%2C50.0270015%5D%2C%5B15.3292159%2C50.0240114%5D%2C%5B15.3339433%2C50.0244362%5D%2C%5B15.3371379%2C50.0271514%5D%2C%5B15.3376541%2C50.031498%5D%2C%5B15.340518%2C50.0339298%5D%2C%5B15.346957%2C50.0329283%5D%2C%5B15.3532778%2C50.0345715%5D%2C%5B15.3610469%2C50.0318515%5D%2C%5B15.3655293%2C50.0283415%5D%2C%5B15.3784025%2C50.0246007%5D%2C%5B15.3942223%2C50.0162445%5D%2C%5B15.3969556%2C50.0185625%5D%2C%5B15.4022783%2C50.0183338%5D%2C%5B15.4020888%2C50.0197968%5D%2C%5B15.3932339%2C50.0206583%5D%2C%5B15.3920018%2C50.0223698%5D%2C%5B15.385031%2C50.0243347%5D%2C%5B15.383268%2C50.0266595%5D%2C%5B15.3821418%2C50.0248152%5D%2C%5B15.3815274%2C50.0269813%5D%2C%5B15.3804665%2C50.0253754%5D%2C%5B15.3792426%2C50.025917%5D%2C%5B15.3743428%2C50.0294937%5D%2C%5B15.3734636%2C50.0347859%5D%2C%5B15.3695889%2C50.0346392%5D%2C%5B15.3666384%2C50.0394245%5D%2C%5B15.3628116%2C50.041087%5D%2C%5B15.3730635%2C50.0432036%5D%2C%5B15.3780732%2C50.0472218%5D%2C%5B15.3856527%2C50.0472561%5D%2C%5B15.388892%2C50.0443888%5D%2C%5B15.39216%2C50.0442043%5D%2C%5B15.3896159%2C50.0475198%5D%2C%5B15.3943902%2C50.0459441%5D%2C%5B15.402595%2C50.0465414%5D%2C%5B15.4014034%2C50.0483683%5D%2C%5B15.4035434%2C50.0505257%5D%2C%5B15.3962372%2C50.0486151%5D%2C%5B15.394535%2C50.0500037%5D%2C%5B15.3969398%2C50.0520049%5D%2C%5B15.3940358%2C50.0504431%5D%2C%5B15.3896418%2C50.052281%5D%2C%5B15.3833997%2C50.0519173%5D%2C%5B15.3753385%2C50.0557371%5D%2C%5B15.3768323%2C50.0574795%5D%2C%5B15.3807552%2C50.0576628%5D%2C%5B15.3805605%2C50.0605402%5D%2C%5B15.3881422%2C50.061425%5D%2C%5B15.3925269%2C50.0591033%5D%2C%5B15.3946303%2C50.0603602%5D%2C%5B15.3940834%2C50.0616654%5D%2C%5B15.3961776%2C50.0607414%5D%2C%5B15.4125822%2C50.0630548%5D%2C%5B15"
cast_6 = ".4134746%2C50.0744661%5D%2C%5B15.4067539%2C50.0804816%5D%2C%5B15.4054916%2C50.0830808%5D%2C%5B15.4066544%2C50.0837547%5D%2C%5B15.4042526%2C50.0860421%5D%2C%5B15.4052905%2C50.0870901%5D%2C%5B15.4088927%2C50.0854556%5D%2C%5B15.4160104%2C50.0890967%5D%2C%5B15.4203786%2C50.0871824%5D%2C%5B15.4280014%2C50.0880659%5D%2C%5B15.4236774%2C50.0883806%5D%2C%5B15.4155121%2C50.0939248%5D%2C%5B15.4098499%2C50.0906237%5D%2C%5B15.4075168%2C50.0919355%5D%2C%5B15.4094691%2C50.0929791%5D%2C%5B15.402386%2C50.0951011%5D%2C%5B15.4009451%2C50.0939897%5D%2C%5B15.4015589%2C50.0959031%5D%2C%5B15.3991191%2C50.0954995%5D%2C%5B15.4078486%2C50.1053316%5D%2C%5B15.4139267%2C50.1076966%5D%2C%5B15.4190626%2C50.1062858%5D%2C%5B15.4204394%2C50.1043623%5D%2C%5B15.419641%2C50.1029451%5D%2C%5B15.425487%2C50.0992095%5D%2C%5B15.4372403%2C50.101709%5D%2C%5B15.4341712%2C50.103413%5D%2C%5B15.4323829%2C50.110828%5D%2C%5B15.4373797%2C50.1098872%5D%2C%5B15.4382373%2C50.112052%5D%2C%5B15.440637%2C50.1119275%5D%2C%5B15.4348981%2C50.1152388%5D%2C%5B15.4399748%2C50.1187849%5D%2C%5B15.4422332%2C50.1186898%5D%2C%5B15.448004%2C50.1245509%5D%2C%5B15.4394162%2C50.1263351%5D%2C%5B15.4424804%2C50.1272179%5D%2C%5B15.4402373%2C50.1285949%5D%2C%5B15.4386249%2C50.1267957%5D%2C%5B15.4242543%2C50.1302151%5D%2C%5B15.4136279%2C50.1360966%5D%2C%5B15.4162801%2C50.1388282%5D%2C%5B15.4153957%2C50.1404655%5D%2C%5B15.4101445%2C50.1389653%5D%2C%5B15.4035614%2C50.1410463%5D%2C%5B15.4057903%2C50.1385907%5D%2C%5B15.4032532%2C50.1349821%5D%2C%5B15.3908308%2C50.1380372%5D%2C%5B15.3896295%2C50.1404446%5D%2C%5B15.3818727%2C50.1455547%5D%2C%5B15.3666429%2C50.1437912%5D%2C%5B15.3314292%2C50.1459439%5D%2C%5B15.3022217%2C50.1566421%5D%2C%5B15.2999343%2C50.159518%5D%2C%5B15.3008151%2C50.1577516%5D%2C%5B15.2919217%2C50.1559134%5D%2C%5B15.2913616%2C50.1515941%5D%2C%5B15.2873242%2C50.1529242%5D%2C%5B15.2850402%2C50.1494766%5D%2C%5B15.2794866%2C50.1508381%5D%2C%5B15.2808718%2C50.1481203%5D%2C%5B15.2717813%2C50.1493956%5D%2C%5B15.2693875%2C50.1511556%5D%2C%5B15.2720351%2C50.1479877%5D%2C%5B15.2764349%2C50.1466513%5D%2C%5B15.2813847%2C50.147562%5D%2C%5B15.2838828%2C50.1461274%5D%2C%5B15.2826681%2C50.1444837%5D%2C%5B15.2784628%2C50.143719%5D%2C%5B15.2796582%2C50.1433122%5D%2C%5B15.2780194%2C50.1409157%5D%2C%5B15.282405%2C50.140849%5D%2C%5B15.2784695%2C50.1381623%5D%2C%5B15.2708307%2C50.1391665%5D%2C%5B15"
cast_7 = ".2668258%2C50.1375857%5D%2C%5B15.269911%2C50.1346072%5D%2C%5B15.2762845%2C50.1329987%5D%2C%5B15.2759419%2C50.1303474%5D%2C%5B15.2793229%2C50.1302371%5D%2C%5B15.281164%2C50.1264982%5D%2C%5B15.2845801%2C50.1261406%5D%2C%5B15.2848885%2C50.1230899%5D%2C%5B15.2828851%2C50.1228826%5D%2C%5B15.2837849%2C50.1179389%5D%2C%5B15.2768798%2C50.117716%5D%2C%5B15.2771028%2C50.1144981%5D%2C%5B15.272524%2C50.1150153%5D%2C%5B15.2713081%2C50.1121539%5D%2C%5B15.2725418%2C50.1105403%5D%2C%5B15.2695258%2C50.1068804%5D%2C%5B15.2674912%2C50.1101226%5D%2C%5B15.2588749%2C50.1105492%5D%2C%5B15.2588528%2C50.109051%5D%2C%5B15.2609659%2C50.1088692%5D%2C%5B15.2592838%2C50.1065069%5D%2C%5B15.2536841%2C50.1067928%5D%2C%5B15.2539585%2C50.1090625%5D%2C%5B15.2525796%2C50.1049205%5D%2C%5B15.2435934%2C50.1060842%5D%2C%5B15.2453384%2C50.098772%5D%2C%5B15.2423646%2C50.0989078%5D%2C%5B15.2423883%2C50.1011124%5D%2C%5B15.2393165%2C50.1013005%5D%2C%5B15.2393185%2C50.1024704%5D%2C%5B15.2334966%2C50.1021718%5D%2C%5B15.2160559%2C50.1071886%5D%2C%5B15.2144357%2C50.1094093%5D%2C%5B15.2039163%2C50.1073611%5D%2C%5B15.2041415%2C50.1086931%5D%2C%5B15.1852359%2C50.1097565%5D%2C%5B15.1833813%2C50.1090549%5D%2C%5B15.1841281%2C50.1078717%5D%2C%5B15.1874227%2C50.1095254%5D%2C%5B15.1907831%2C50.1079763%5D%2C%5B15.1922237%2C50.1051987%5D%2C%5B15.191224%2C50.1027416%5D%2C%5B15.1841377%2C50.1017764%5D%2C%5B15.1760019%2C50.1032842%5D%2C%5B15.1773527%2C50.0987535%5D%2C%5B15.1731946%2C50.0978941%5D%2C%5B15.1751755%2C50.0963999%5D%2C%5B15.1743437%2C50.0952196%5D%2C%5B15.1696704%2C50.0961228%5D%2C%5B15.1711029%2C50.0927787%5D%2C%5B15.169623%2C50.0915337%5D%2C%5B15.1653342%2C50.0951398%5D%2C%5B15.1613706%2C50.0942165%5D%2C%5B15.1581873%2C50.1000534%5D%2C%5B15.1550458%2C50.0984016%5D%2C%5B15.1465104%2C50.0981989%5D%2C%5B15.1465095%2C50.0995308%5D%2C%5B15.1357627%2C50.0982693%5D%2C%5B15.1313868%2C50.0962456%5D%2C%5B15.1253349%2C50.0992604%5D%2C%5B15.1258172%2C50.1009654%5D%2C%5B15.1204803%2C50.1016614%5D%2C%5B15.1218891%2C50.0947834%5D%2C%5B15.1188048%2C50.0935699%5D%2C%5B15.1155421%2C50.0831571%5D%2C%5B15.1093235%2C50.0843775%5D%2C%5B15.1081288%2C50.0825619%5D%2C%5B15.0999571%2C50.0878321%5D%2C%5B15.1013205%2C50.0922107%5D%2C%5B15.0915809%2C50.0931084%5D%2C%5B15.0920168%2C50.0949287%5D%2C%5B15.0863782%2C50.0966826%5D%2C%5B15.086481%2C50.0944002%5D%2C%5B15.0826752%2C50.0941637%5D%2C%5B15"
cast_8 = ".068619%2C50.0973604%5D%2C%5B15.0703038%2C50.101897%5D%2C%5B15.0740585%2C50.1044897%5D%2C%5B15.0764522%2C50.1039785%5D%2C%5B15.0736102%2C50.1060177%5D%2C%5B15.0629614%2C50.1074685%5D%2C%5B15.0565328%2C50.105559%5D%2C%5B15.0564676%2C50.1038553%5D%2C%5B15.0533182%2C50.1015993%5D%2C%5B15.0516594%2C50.1040076%5D%2C%5B15.0458835%2C50.1020048%5D%2C%5B15.0448312%2C50.1041812%5D%2C%5B15.0466144%2C50.1126407%5D%2C%5B15.0457175%2C50.1149513%5D%2C%5B15.0343113%2C50.1170375%5D%2C%5B15.0345083%2C50.114516%5D%2C%5B15.0301261%2C50.1146343%5D%2C%5B15.0264935%2C50.1113655%5D%2C%5B15.0170356%2C50.1140104%5D%2C%5B15.0119161%2C50.11321%5D%2C%5B15.0045907%2C50.1162478%5D%2C%5B15.0045718%2C50.1108536%5D%2C%5B15.0027007%2C50.1105543%5D%2C%5B15.004638%2C50.1101266%5D%2C%5B15.0039322%2C50.1047413%5D%2C%5B15.005155%2C50.1043048%5D%2C%5B14.998137%2C50.0967009%5D%2C%5B14.9596509%2C50.1052427%5D%2C%5B14.955716%2C50.1030399%5D%2C%5B14.9618513%2C50.0988074%5D%2C%5B14.9624361%2C50.0959271%5D%2C%5B14.9534678%2C50.0972712%5D%2C%5B14.9537379%2C50.093282%5D%2C%5B14.9511217%2C50.0933379%5D%2C%5B14.9534407%2C50.0882163%5D%2C%5B14.948147%2C50.0876311%5D%2C%5B14.9480446%2C50.0931762%5D%2C%5B14.9450619%2C50.089111%5D%2C%5B14.9445069%2C50.0901939%5D%2C%5B14.9419088%2C50.089393%5D%2C%5B14.941649%2C50.0905889%5D%2C%5B14.9436269%2C50.090921%5D%2C%5B14.9292988%2C50.0919269%5D%2C%5B14.9302586%2C50.0950085%5D%2C%5B14.9272723%2C50.095255%5D%2C%5B14.9267884%2C50.0914298%5D%2C%5B14.9249778%2C50.0917708%5D%2C%5B14.9268745%2C50.0926059%5D%2C%5B14.9258074%2C50.0979741%5D%2C%5B14.9314785%2C50.1019029%5D%2C%5B14.9320943%2C50.1066867%5D%2C%5B14.9413214%2C50.1105662%5D%2C%5B14.9474381%2C50.1112535%5D%2C%5B14.9460171%2C50.1142574%5D%2C%5B14.9409307%2C50.117369%5D%2C%5B14.9450905%2C50.1184205%5D%2C%5B14.9422467%2C50.119131%5D%2C%5B14.9419262%2C50.1213203%5D%2C%5B14.9377646%2C50.1221107%5D%2C%5B14.9293773%2C50.1215114%5D%2C%5B14.9277818%2C50.1181327%5D%2C%5B14.91945%2C50.1202597%5D%2C%5B14.9064761%2C50.1161503%5D%2C%5B14.9114208%2C50.1130913%5D%2C%5B14.8973812%2C50.1101211%5D%2C%5B14.9026135%2C50.1041702%5D%2C%5B14.8862235%2C50.1046495%5D%2C%5B14.882639%2C50.1016048%5D%2C%5B14.8737914%2C50.0991642%5D%2C%5B14.8736091%2C50.0977705%5D%2C%5B14.8640719%2C50.096482%5D%2C%5B14.8380862%2C50.1029933%5D%2C%5B14.8353495%2C50.1065255%5D%2C%5B14.8203159%2C50.1075386%5D%2C%5B14.8178407%2C50.10837%5D%2C%5B14"
cast_9 = ".8174777%2C50.1109162%5D%2C%5B14.8078363%2C50.1109486%5D%2C%5B14.8082064%2C50.1099036%5D%2C%5B14.8065928%2C50.1097325%5D%2C%5B14.8031871%2C50.1151496%5D%2C%5B14.7909845%2C50.112214%5D%2C%5B14.791537%2C50.1159915%5D%2C%5B14.7898356%2C50.1161527%5D%2C%5B14.7888326%2C50.1127876%5D%2C%5B14.7836591%2C50.1126201%5D%2C%5B14.7851984%2C50.1109994%5D%2C%5B14.783707%2C50.1101127%5D%2C%5B14.7799914%2C50.1100845%5D%2C%5B14.7794878%2C50.1121285%5D%2C%5B14.7765771%2C50.112093%5D%2C%5B14.7678175%2C50.1091971%5D%2C%5B14.7649339%2C50.1046049%5D%2C%5B14.7632564%2C50.1067252%5D%2C%5B14.7619325%2C50.1062309%5D%2C%5B14.7632773%2C50.1032313%5D%2C%5B14.7594198%2C50.099077%5D%2C%5B14.7363085%2C50.0943267%5D%2C%5B14.7384606%2C50.0924892%5D%2C%5B14.7376811%2C50.0912459%5D%2C%5B14.7305199%2C50.0868433%5D%5D%5D%7D%7D&center=%5B15.181636455691432%2C50.02066883782007%5D&zoom=11.111617917065713&locationInput=okres%20Kol%C3%ADn%2C%20St%C5%99edo%C4%8Desk%C3%BD%20kraj%2C%20St%C5%99edn%C3%AD%20%C4%8Cechy%2C%20%C4%8Cesko&limit=15"

URL = 'https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vyhledat#offerType=prodej&estateType=byt&disposition=3-kk%2C3-1%2C4-kk%2C4-1%2C5-kk%2C5-1%2C6-kk%2C6-1%2C7-kk%2C7-1&ownership=&construction=&equipped=&balcony=&order=timeOrder_desc&boundary=%7B%22type%22%3A%22Feature%22%2C%22properties%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22geometry%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22Polygon%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B%5B%5B14.7305199%2C50.0868433%5D%2C%5B14.7347907%2C50.0851368%5D%2C%5B14.7335681%2C50.0820115%5D%2C%5B14.7365932%2C50.0818778%5D%2C%5B14.7369494%2C50.0836348%5D%2C%5B14.7440628%2C50.0834312%5D%2C%5B14.7442786%2C50.081928%5D%2C%5B14.7491301%2C50.0819783%5D%2C%5B14.7501216%2C50.0801764%5D%2C%5B14.7422156%2C50.0785401%5D%2C%5B14.7385155%2C50.0708815%5D%2C%5B14.753382%2C50.0710775%5D%2C%5B14.7541288%2C50.0684731%5D%2C%5B14.7520195%2C50.067327%5D%2C%5B14.7522295%2C50.0657011%5D%2C%5B14.' + cast_2 + cast_3 + cast_4 + cast_5 + cast_6 + cast_7 + cast_8 + cast_9
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'product__body-new'})
for job_data in results:
    cena = job_data.find('strong', attrs={'class':'product__value'})
    cena_final = cena.text.strip()

    print(cena_final)
```

It is works but no show price in `<strong class="product__value">5.990.000 Kč</strong>` and others values, it start and end immediately.

I **need** print:

```
Kolín, Středočeský kraj
Prodej bytu 2+kk, 46 m²
3.480.000 Kč

Jateční, Kolín, Středočeský kraj
Prodej bytu 3+1, 73 m²
4.500.000 Kč
```

Comment: Is that content dynamically loaded? Can you find the prices when looking at the page source?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, If I load the URL in question code, I press F12 and in console I see these values. In the code is whole url, but in qeustion is short url because in finding is too long 5000 length.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the page does not return any divs with a class of "product__body-new".

Comment: There is `<div class="product__body-new">` and in this div is for example `<p>` element with data I need.

Comment: I have run your sample, up to the point it gets the page, and saved it. No such element was in the response. Are you checking the response via python or are you looking it up in a browser if you run the request manually from the browser? It may return different results.

Comment: I try it in browser with press F12 - in console mode show this div but if I try find all divs, it not show my divs what I want. How to get data which I want from this website? Is there any API or something?

Comment: the site probably needs some cookies to work. the fact yout browser has those, does not mean the python interpreter has them too. You problably need to find out how the auhtentication works on the site and then get a cookie using that mechanism.